# Is it correct to combine multiple clauses into one sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, writing, writing-style

Is it correct to combine multiple clauses (sub sentences) into one?

For example, let us consider this sentence:

> *On managerial side, I am experienced in accounting software, have been working throughout the life cycle of product, and have
>   considerable experience for enhancing and improving existing
>   products.*

Here I am combining 3 clauses to make they one sentence, so I am wondering if it is grammatical?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with combining multiple clauses, but you have several other mistakes in your sentence (missing _the_s, redundant "for" in "have experience _for_", and it's not obvious whether the leading clause "on the managerial side" applies to all three sub-clauses).

Comment: Thanks @aaamos. Can you please correct my sentence and write it in full ? 

Thanks once again.

Comment: Your statement is a bit ambiguous. Does 'on the managerial side' mean that you have actual management experience (using accounting software)?  In which case the other experience you quote doesn't seem to flow and ought to be separate sentences.  OR do you intend that you have experience developing *managerial* software, i.e., accounting software, and if so you ought to say that explicitly.

Comment: See JLG's answer for a corrected version of your sentence. Do consider @Jim's comment though, which I think is a good point.

Comment: See the funny side of this: "The book [The Rotters' Club] held the record for the longest sentence in English literature with 13,955 words. That record was broken by Nigel Tomm's one-sentence, 469,375-word book, The Blah Story, Volume 4." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rotters%27_Club_(novel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple clauses in a sentence. The clauses need to be parallel in structure. Your clauses are okay grammatically (I am..., have been..., have.) but the sentence is a little clumsy (which I think you sense). With a long sentence, you will want to delete unnecessary words and make the clauses strictly parallel.

I would suggest rewording your sentence to something like this:

> On the managerial side, I have extensive experience with accounting software, a history of working with *this product* throughout its life cycle*, and a demonstrated talent for improving existing products.

(*I'm not sure of the meaning of this clause in your original sentence, so I am not sure if this is what you meant. It might also be better to name the product where I have *this product.*)

In this revision, I use the verb *have* once and each clause is now a noun clause...experience, history, talent.